# SQL Statement querying same table 2 times

Tags: sql

Ok, I've got brain cells melting at an alarming rate on this SQL statement.  Not my database, but I've been tasked with extracting data.  So here's what I'm dealing with...

It is medical data.  We have a database where ALL of the people are listed in one table- patients, as well as doctors.  Each person has a unique `PersonID`.  Let's just start with the `Person` table:

```
Person:
PersonID, PersonType, LastName, FirstName
```

I have another table that is hospital admissions.

```
Admissions:
AdmissionID, PersonID and PrimaryMD
```

where the Primary MD is the same as the Person ID for a doctor.

I need to extract each Admission, with the last name, and then the first name of the patient, but then I need to go back, based on the PrimaryMD identifier and use that value to pull the last name and first name of the doctor so that my results look like:

`Admission | PatientLastName | PatientFirstName | DoctorLastName | DoctorFirstName`

Ultimately, I'll need to pull address information for both the patient, and the doctor which is all stored in an address table with the same `PersonID` as in the person table, and then pull the doctor's address using the primarymd against the person table.  But I can't figure how to write two queries in the same statement against these similar columns.  I tried using aliases, and some left and inner joins and even a union, but I can't seem to get things right.

Any assistance would be hugely appreciated.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: What is the query that you have tried?

Comment: Have you even attempted anything??  If you do, post your query.  If not, get to work.

Comment: Yeah, I've been working on this for 5 days already.  It is in Sybase.  And I'm basically learning this as I do it.  Here's what I have.  I have very little experience at all with this, but with what I'm pasting below, I am getting my active admissions, by sites that are appropriate but the last column Address1 is giving me the patient address and I don't know how to write the join to go back and pull the doctor's address.  Here is what I have so far:

Comment: SELECT "Admission"."AdmissionID", "Person"."LastName", "Person"."FirstName", "Admission"."SiteID", "Address"."Address1" ,  "PatientOther"."MedRecNum",  "Admission"."PrimaryMD"  ,"Address"."Address1"
FROM   "DBA"."Person" 
INNER JOIN "DBA"."Admission" on "Person"."PersonID" = "Admission"."PersonID"
INNER JOIN "DBA"."Address" on "Admission"."PersonID"="Address"."PersonID"
INNER JOIN "DBA"."PatientOther" on "Admission"."PersonId"="PatientOther"."PersonID"

WHERE "Admission"."AdmissionState"='A' AND "Address"."Address1"!= '' AND (
"Admission"."SiteID" ='2011')
Order By "LastName"

Comment: I am getting the patient address info, but the last column address is coming back the same as the patient address.  I've clipped out a lot of other fields so i could paste it in here

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT
a.AdmissionID,
pat.LastName AS PatientLastName,
pat.FirstName AS PatientFirstName,
doc.LastName AS DoctorLastName,
doc.FirstName AS DoctorFirstName

FROM Admissions a

INNER JOIN Person pat
ON a.PersonID = pat.PersonID

INNER JOIN Person doc
ON a.PrimaryMD = doc.PersonID
```

For getting addresses use the same steps:

```
SELECT
a.AdmissionID,
pat.LastName AS PatientLastName,
pat.FirstName AS PatientFirstName,
doc.LastName AS DoctorLastName,
doc.FirstName AS DoctorFirstName

FROM Admissions a

INNER JOIN Person pat
ON a.PersonID = pat.PersonID

INNER JOIN Person doc
ON a.PrimaryMD = doc.PersonID

INNER JOIN Addresses addPat
ON pat.PersonID = addPat.PersonID

INNER JOIN Addresses addDoc
ON doc.PersonID = addDoc.PersonID
```

Comment: I don't know how to mark this answered, but thank you Gonzalo Lorieto!!!  This is exactly what I needed.  This works perfectly